# Calling CreateIndex with settings without using ImmutableSettings

Tags: java, elasticsearch-jest

In the Jest readme there is an example of creating index with settings but it uses the `ImmutableSettings` class from ElasticSearch library.

Unfortunately due to some conflicts, we can't include ElasticSearch library in our project. Is there a way to use CreateIndex.Builder to create index with settings without using `ImmutableSettings` class from ElasticSearch library?

```
String settings = "\"settings\" : {\n" +
            "        \"number_of_shards\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"number_of_replicas\" : 1\n" +
            "    }\n";
client.execute(new CreateIndex.Builder("articles").settings(ImmutableSettings.builder().loadFromSource(settings).build().getAsMap()).build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [CreateIndexIntegrationTest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/d99556f466fc02337b381610ed7378450decbbd3/jest/src/test/java/io/searchbox/indices/CreateIndexIntegrationTest.java) which has live examples of both (with and without Elasticsearch builders) usage styles and **please do read the [README](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/README.md#further-reading)** which explicitly recommends the integration tests for actual-use examples.

Comment: Thanks Cihat for directing me to the integration test. I had gone to the integration test link from the README which goes to the core integration tests. I should have realized to look into other packages for other tests.